# Subshell inside quotes

Tags: bash, quoting, command-substitution, subshell

I'm writing a small shell script like this:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Bearer "$(printf  user:pass | base64)"' 'https://api.com/v1/auth'
```

To debug I switched to echo:

```
echo 'Bearer "$(printf  remote-key-sync:2klic-hlqDZPGmqJTwhqVkPubld9ReXAnQSks | base64)"'
```

But the result is:

```
Bearer "$(printf  remote-key-sync:2klic-hlqDZPGmqJTwhqVkPubld9ReXAnQSks | base64)"
```

How can I update my curl command so that it sends --header 'Bearer myBase64String' with the subshell results inside the single quote?

Comment: Remove the outer single quotes. Otherwise the `$()` would not be executed by bash. Replace them with double quotes instead.

Comment: Your original code is broken for the same reason; the header contains the literal string `$(printf user:pass | base64)`, not the base64-encoded credentials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by refactoring your code.

```
bearer="Bearer \"$(printf user:pass | base64)\""
curl -X POST --header "$bearer" 'https://api.com/v1/auth'
```

Now when you go to debug, you don't need to quote the argument(s) again.

```
echo curl -X POST --header "$bearer" 'https://api.com/v1/auth'
```